# Создание объекта

Tags: java, ооп

Поправьте меня, если у меня неправильный ход мыслей.

Сначала создаем объект: `new String();`

Теперь надо объявить переменную, которая будет хранить ссылку на объект: `String s = new String();`

Теперь мы можем использовать методы созданного объекта, описанные в классе `String`, например `s.charAt(0);`.

А если я сделаю вот так `Object obj = new String();` то то мне будут доступны только методы класса `Object`. Почему так? Ведь я через ссылку буду обращаться к созданному экземпляра класса `String`?

Answer (score 7):

Потому что доступные члены класса определяются **типом ссылочной переменной**, а не типом объекта, на который она ссылается.

**Суперклассу** `Object` **неизвестно**, что в него добавляет подкласс `String`.

В то же время, Вы можете обратиться к методам подкласса путем явного приведения типа:

```
char firstChar = ((String) obj).charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 4):

`Mercedes` наследник класса `Car`. Представь что `String` это `Mercedes`, а `Object` - машина (`Car`)! У мерседеса есть возможность поворачивать колеса изменяя вертикальное положение. У других машин, такой функции нет. Ты создаешь класс машины не указывая ее марку. Значит фичи этой машины тебе не доступны. Ты можешь только рулить, жать газ и тормозить!